# how to add Custom column to External List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have been able to create external list to the share point site. In addition to those existing fields derived from External database, i am looking to insert a lookup field (column) to this external list. can someone assist me how do i insert a new field at External List ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

External Lists do not support the addition of custom columns.

The data for a custom column would need to be stored somewhere, so in the external database. You would need to add a column/field there and make the BDC connection read and write. To emulate the lookup column, you will need to add JavaScript to the edit forms and get the data using a REST call.

Comment: you could reverse it and make a list with just the new field and link it to the bdc list. this would cause a lot of work since you would need to create an entry for each item in the list (lots of work... )